# Как исключить определённые JpaRepository при поиске кандидатов для Spring Data MongoDB?

Tags: java, spring, spring-jpa

В проекте используются 2 СУБД: Mongo и Postgres. В логах пестрят сообщения вроде

```
RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data MongoDB - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface ru.rtlabs.sis.services.dao.repositories.DepartmentRepository.
```

Сама Entity

```
public interface DepartmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Department, Long> { }
@Data
@Table(name = "departments")
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Department {
 ...
}
```

Базы подключены как

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db
    username: postgres
    password: postgres    
  data.mongodb:
    host: localhost
    port: 27017
    database: db
```

Как исключить определённые JpaRepository при поиске кандидатов для Spring Data MongoDB?

Пробовал отключать redis

```
data:
    mongodb:
      host: localhost
      port: 27017
      database: dbsisattachments
    redis.repositories.enabled : false
```

не помогло

Пробовал принудительно прописывать. @EnableJpaRepositories со списком пакетов. Не помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поместите репозитории каждой БД в разные пакеты и с помощью параметра basePackages или basePackageClasses аннотаций EnableJpaRepositories и EnableMongoRepositories укажите эти пакеты

Comment: А это не одно и то же? "Пробовал принудительно прописывать. @EnableJpaRepositories со списком пакетов. Не помогло"

Comment: В EnableMongoRepositories вы указывали пакеты? Если этого не сделать, будут сканиться все